# ls -1tr | tail -1 doesn't work in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I have a weird situation here... two out of three of my servers refuse to give any output to the command `ls -1tr | tail -1`

There are definitely files in the directory but it gives no output what so ever (returns nothing and goes back to the prompt)... simply typing `ls` or `ls -c` works but not `ls -1tr | tail -1`

x2 Server 2003

x1 Server 2008

Only one of the Server 2003 gives the correct response to the command.

I have put the /bin directory in the windows environmental path field so I don't think that is the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the more formal `ls -1tr | tail -n 1` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tail -[number]` syntax is no longer valid by POSIX.1-2008. Maybe you are using different versions of the coreutils and that is why you are experiencing different results.
The correct syntax is  `ls -1tr | tail -n 1`.

Comment: Your "corrected" syntax is uncorrected.

Comment: When I try that on the two servers that did not work before, I now get the message:

"TAIL: can't open 1"

Comment: Besides from trying to upgrade your cygwin installations, you could try to use `ls -1tr | tail --lines=1`.

Comment: Updated the installation but still receiving the same message "TAIL: can't open 1"... @p.vitzliputzli when I tried that command, I got a "TAIL: lseeki64() failed 22" message - not sure what that means.

Comment: Errno 22 is probably EINVAL, i.e. invalid argument. It sounds like you have encountered a cygwin bug. Nevertheless, could you please post the coreutils/tail-version? `tail --version`

Comment: tail --version throws a "TAIL:lseeki64() failed 9" error - it looks like a completely messed up install to me (or a lot of missing components) - it may be worth installing to a completely different directory to see if I get the same issue - what do you think?

Comment: Yes, I would try that with the default installation.

Comment: @p.vitzliputzli - great, it works now with the commands above! One small problem though, when I run my batch script which has the following in it "C:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "script.sh" - it tries to use the old bash from the previous installation (the new installation is C:\cygwin and the old one was in C:\ssh) - are you aware of any config or why the bash.exe in the new installation dir is still using or pointing to the old one? Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Maybe you have to change the PATH-var in Windows to your new cygwin installation.

Comment: p.vitzliputzli@ Already tried that... hmm strange

Comment: Apparently, there are some keys in the registry. Could you search for "cygwin" with regedit?

Comment: @p.vitzliputzli I did that but got the same issue - I looked at it again today (after some rest :D) and managed to see the problem - I was just using the "-c" switch instead of "--login -c -c" - thanks for all your help! :-)